# ERROR TypeError: this._http.request(...).share is not a function

Tags: angular

When I try to authorize, I get this error:

> ERROR TypeError: this._http.request(...).share is not a function
>
> at AuthService.request (auth.service.ts:569)
>
> at AuthService.post (auth.service.ts:502)
>
> at AuthService.signIn (auth.service.ts:166)
>
> at SignInComponent.signIn (sign-in.component.ts:35)
>
> at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (SignInComponent.html:24)
>
> at handleEvent (core.js:13547)
>
> at callWithDebugContext (core.js:15056)
>
> at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:14643)
>
> at dispatchEvent (core.js:9962)
>
> at eval (core.js:10587)

I just can't find where she is, who can help please. Two routing and two modules are used.

Here is a listing of some files. If you need to throw something else, write. Though here on ideas all listings where there can be an error.

app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from "@angular/platform-browser/animations";
import { NgModule  } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { ToastModule, ToastOptions } from "ng2-toastr";
import { ToastCustomOptions } from "./shared/toast-cutom-options";

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { routing } from './routings/routing.module';

import { SignInModule } from './layout/sign-in/sign-in.module';
import { LayoutModule } from './layout/layout.module';

import { User } from "./models/user.model";
import { AuthGuard } from './shared/guards/auth.guard';
import { AuthService } from './services/auth/auth.service';
import { environment } from "../environments/environment";

declare let moment: any;

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    SignInModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    LayoutModule,
    routing,
    ToastModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [AuthService, AuthGuard,  {provide: ToastOptions, useClass: ToastCustomOptions} ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { 
  constructor(public authService: AuthService) {
    moment.locale('ru');

    this.authService.init({
      apiPath: environment.apiUrl,
      signInRedirect: 'sign_in',
      signInPath: '/sign_in',
      validateTokenFailedRedirect: 'sign_in',
      signOutFailedValidate: true,
      dataStorage: localStorage,
      userDataClass: User
    });
  }
}
```

router.module.ts:

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';

import { LayoutComponent} from '../layout/layout.component';

import { SignInComponent } from '../layout/sign-in/sign-in.component';

import { NotFoundComponent } from '../layout/not-found/not-found.component';

import { AuthGuard } from '../shared/guards/auth.guard';

export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'sign_in',   component: SignInComponent },
  { path: 'dashboard',   component: LayoutComponent },
  { path: 'not_found',   component: NotFoundComponent },
  { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent }

];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true });
```

Comment: Usually, there is a Stacktrace with your error, which should show you where the error was thrown. Can you add it to your question?

Comment: @Nikolaus Added by

Comment: @ShashankVivek An argument of type "Request"cannot be assigned to a parameter of type"string".

Comment: I havent worked with `share()` but from the error `.request()` doesnt provide `share` .

Comment: whats your `rxjs` version?

Comment: @Vikas   "rxjs": "^5.5.6"

Answer (score 0):

let response = this._http.request(new Request(baseRequestOptions)).share();

baseRequestOptions should be of type object.

From your code it is not clear whether it is an object or not. 
Check typeof(baseRequestOptions) if it is not object then modify your code.

Example Code :

```
constructor(public http:Http) {}
  request(url:string) {
    return this.http.request(new Request({
     method: RequestMethod.Get,
     url: url,
     search: 'password=123'
  })).share();
}
```

Comment: there can be no error in auth.service I have a program with this auth.service and everything works there

Comment: But from your error it's clear that there is an error in baseRequestOptions . Have you checked baseRequestOptions by logging it in console.

Comment: checked    typeof (baseRequestOptions)
"undefined"

Comment: ok. log both data and type of baseRequestOptions before  and after merging it with options .Then you will get idea where it is really going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`RxJS v5.5.2+` has moved to `Pipeable` operators to improve tree shaking and make it easier to create custom operators.
 now `operators` need to be  combined using the `pipe` method
**[Refer This](https://blog.angularindepth.com/rxjs-understanding-lettable-operators-fe74dda186d3)**
**New Import**

```
import { share} from 'rxjs/operators';
```

**Example**

```
this.response$=this.http.get('url').pipe(share());
```

Apart from it You are using `HttpModule` which is **deprecated** you should use **[HttpClientModule](https://angular.io/guide/http)** instead